# Token returned by B2C is not decoded by JWT.MS

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows. I created the signup/signin user flow and I just tried using it. I am choosing Google provider since I have it defined. I type-in my country and display name, since I selected these parameters to be required. Then I'm redirected to my app's redirect URI, which is https://jwt.ms. The redirect is:

> https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ..Q45eRY9bXPGXqmqn.WFmA7ERvYw2gsZgAy8zjdBNsxp-fX828V0DMhwLfIw3XTk1cYiIXOaBT0uUkT8HA9mZfJJDBYodM_Ca3xt17lCqGoUHyS8pOtfZQ8pqfOTxdCL6-llVAQYKV9vHKPxWDXYhLxS9sDNTmVUGfALgxPeiZj8nZs9i7ZzFzYXtNyAIATrMSX-r4lGGMWxFgsNp-Vhk7PXZ2_8bgzXiFGLgPXCwVROD_WR7EEMSGTgN_ECbtsRz-ATriYS5s5tfzHhv1cT2f4ELB-OY84bl1nk5LOjSPBoDqXIX-K-pLb6lvXJ4WDFwjzNE7RDcNHlfnNeOivXoPPb4CmAdQvy3SpRJG6i00PgnuDryPOlUEubNoTloB4VPYM_l1n9ueilHugJbKG7B7HxTz5SFDI450dbrv0PSxG47tyC4o3RJ8KMxa4jT5mDEcI7szWQGpVJp_YMDq5yk47ZnDuZ5PnQYoxvzTPHEKVdi6CVsCslBdnxZk61Ep2pKbwa7zvFujS0E14srCOPCnVsE0NwUXx74c1a7H-mRqLCuH0Q0byplcEY1r8xS-ftvRDs1ahRCjxVIBrob9dJSy3bpRsi8wef1KB3wuhWJQMw.WNAXijIJxquWcAqzHeOJXA

The thing is, the JWT.MS does not decode it, I just see:

[image]

I tried pasting my token into the box, but nothing happens. I also tried using JWT.IO with the same token. I get the information:

> Invalid Signature

Why does B2C return to me an invalid token?

Comment: The same thing happens when I try to sign up with an email instead of Google - I just checked that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing was I did not enable implicit tokens in my app registration's Authentication blade.

Comment: Yep, you can see in the URL it responded with (authorisation)code, not id_token.

Comment: What is an example of the login uri that redirects back to jwt.ms successfully?